# Javascript - Use elements in array to filter array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to filter an array of objects, based on the elements within another array.

The array of objects I would like filtered is:

```
const data = [
{id: 1, method: "bike"},
{id: 2, method: "walk"},
{id: 3, method: "bus"},
{id: 4, method: "bike"},
{id: 5, method: "walk"},
{id: 5, method: "bus"},
]
```

I have one of three arrays that have what `method` I would like to include

```
const filter1 = ['bike'];
const filter2 = ['bike', 'walk'];
const filter3 = ['bike', 'walk', 'bus'];
```

I am able to `push` the filtered array to a new array, but I would like the filtered array to have the same structure as `data`, instead of an array of arrays.

This is my current method, and it gives me a 2D array:

```
let output = [];
const filterArr = filter2.forEach(element => {
 const filt = data.filter(el => el.method === element);
 output.push(filt);
});
```

My desired output is:

```
const want = [
    {id: 1, method: "bike"},
    {id: 2, method: "walk"},
    {id: 4, method: "bike"},
    {id: 5, method: "walk"},
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would convert the filter `Array` to a `Set`, and use the `Set.prototype.has` method to check if the current item's `method` exists within it.

```js
const filter2 = new Set(['bike', 'walk']);

const data = [
  { id: 1, method: "bike" },
  { id: 2, method: "walk" },
  { id: 3, method: "bus"  },
  { id: 4, method: "bike" },
  { id: 5, method: "walk" },
  { id: 5, method: "bus"  },
];

const filtered = data.filter(({ method }) => filter2.has(method));

console.log(filtered);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a filter array as methods and check if the method of the data array is included in the filter array.

```
methods = filter2, // one of your filters.
result = data.filter(({ method }) => methods.includes(method));
```